# Charge on electrode and voltage

Tags: charge, voltage

I have a long perforated tube that is a  positively charged electrode with total surface area A. If I put a charge on the electrode using a Van de Graaff device how do I determine voltage created by the charge? In other words how do I relate charge to voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Voltage is relative to something else, lets take that something else as ground. Your electrode will have some capacitance with respect to that ground. Since $C = Q/V$, the voltage will be $V = Q/C$ for an applied charge $Q$ and electrode capacitance $C$.